# Scripts not showing up in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I added these scripts to the header and footer of the theme I'm working on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php wp_head();?>
        
    </head>
<body <?php body_class();?>>
```

```
<?php wp_footer();?>

</body>
</html>
```

In functions.php, I also added:

```
<?php

function load_stylesheets()
{
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('stylesheet');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');

function include_jquery()
{
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', '', 1, true);
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery');

function load_js()
{
    wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', '', 1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

When I inspect the local site, I don't see these scripts or any other scripts I enqueued in functions.php. Only scripts I could find:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/13.1.0\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/13.1.0\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/localhost\/financeblog\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.8.2"}};
            !function(e,a,t){var n,r,o,i=a.createElement("canvas"),p=i.getContext&&i.getContext("2d");function s(e,t){var a=String.fromCharCode;p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,e),0,0);e=i.toDataURL();return p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,t),0,0),e===i.toDataURL()}function c(e){var t=a.createElement("script");t.src=e,t.defer=t.type="text/javascript",a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)}for(o=Array("flag","emoji"),t.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},r=0;r<o.length;r++)t.supports[o[r]]=function(e){if(!p||!p.fillText)return!1;switch(p.textBaseline="top",p.font="600 32px Arial",e){case"flag":return s([127987,65039,8205,9895,65039],[127987,65039,8203,9895,65039])?!1:!s([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819])&&!s([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]);case"emoji":return!s([10084,65039,8205,55357,56613],[10084,65039,8203,55357,56613])}return!1}(o[r]),t.supports.everything=t.supports.everything&&t.supports[o[r]],"flag"!==o[r]&&(t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&t.supports[o[r]]);t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!t.supports.flag,t.DOMReady=!1,t.readyCallback=function(){t.DOMReady=!0},t.supports.everything||(n=function(){t.readyCallback()},a.addEventListener?(a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n,!1),e.addEventListener("load",n,!1)):(e.attachEvent("onload",n),a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===a.readyState&&t.readyCallback()})),(n=t.source||{}).concatemoji?c(n.concatemoji):n.wpemoji&&n.twemoji&&(c(n.twemoji),c(n.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
```

All css still show up in sources, just not the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

How do your main page templates look? (eg. index.php, single.php, page.php)

Each page should use special functions to include:

- header.php using `get_header();`
- footer.php using `get_footer();`

Here is how single.php looks in WordPress twentytwenyone theme:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty_One
 * @since Twenty Twenty-One 1.0
 */

get_header();

/* Start the Loop */
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

    // Template and article navigation includes here.

endwhile; // End of the loop.

get_footer();
```

Try this code for including scripts and style:

```
/**
 * Load custom scripts and styles.
 */
function custom_scripts_and_styles() {

    // Enqueue styles.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'md-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'md-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), false, 'all' );

    // Enqueue scripts.
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array(), 1, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'md-customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), 1, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts_and_styles' );
```

Comment: Currently, my index.php looks like so only:

<?php get_header();?>

<?php get_footer();?>

js doesn't show up when I view source.

Comment: I updated my answer with enqueue code.

Comment: The scripts still do not show up. The CSS does though.

Comment: I think this issue was syntax-related. I fixed it by adding adding :         <?php wp_head(); ?> Before it was         <?php wp_head();?> (no space between ; and ?)